# systemd - run command every 5 mins and at round time (**:00, **:05, **:10, ...)

Tags: linux, systemd, cron

I've built a program and I want to run it every 5 mins at *round* time (**:00, **:05, **:10, ..., **not** **:01, **:06, **:11, ... or **:03, **:08, **:13, ...).

As I've read, it's better to use systemd than crontab, so I want to use systemd.
And I understand how to launch program every 5 mins, but it doesn't launch at *round* time. I know I can try to launch the program at **:00 so next time it will launch at **:05 and etc, but it seems to be a too silly way.

How do I launch program like this with systemd? Or I can't do it with systemd and I should use crontab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a nice shortcut, but you can do this by listing the possible times in [`OnCalendar=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#OnCalendar=):

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55:00
```

in normalised form.

systemd usually allows itself a minute of leeway on calendar events; you can tighten this by specifying [`AccuracySec=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#AccuracySec=).

Comment: Yep, it works nice! Thank you!